# Plotting graph using plt scatter ( only show 4 dots)

Tags: matplotlib, machine-learning, svm

```
X=new.iloc[:,:-1]
y =new.iloc[:,29]
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=10)
machine1 = svm.LinearSVC()
machine1.fit(X_train,y_train)
y_pred = machine1.predict(X_test)

plt.axis("off");
plt.scatter(y_test,y_pred)
```

*i'm trying to predict between two classes, when i try to plot graph, i'm getting only 4 dots on my plotting graph, anyone know what's wrong with my codes ?
and my train and test shape:
Train (1668, 29) (1668,)
Test (715, 29) (715,)
and i've already print the y_pred and it show like this :
[1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1
 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0
 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 1
 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 1
 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1
 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0
 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1
 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0
 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 0
 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0
 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1
 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1
 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1
 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0
 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0
 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0]*

Comment: Without any data to run your code, how do you expect the readers to help you figure out the problem? Try printing `y_test,y_pred` to see how many points you have. May be you have only 4 points or may be you have several points but only 4 unique values

Comment: Since you are new to Stack Overflow, you should read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Check what your y_pred are being generated.

Comment: Results are true as 0 and 1 makes in total 4 combinations possible. 0,0 0,1 1,0 and 1,1 . Nothing wrong.

Comment: @SauravJoshi ohh..ok..i'm new to machine learning.thanks btw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Results are true as 0 and 1 makes in total 4 combinations possible. 
0,0 0,1 1,0 and 1,1 .
Nothing wrong